# How to use mysqli_info on Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, yii2

So I know this function requires a mysqli_connect() but is there a way to use it with the Yii2 connection?

here is the php manual for the function:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.info.php

Comment: Yii2 use PDO  ... , so take a look a this driver for check if  there is a similar function  ..but normally the   this kind of request are managed by audit module .. (tipically an extension)

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, I hope you want to check the last executed query is successfully executed or not, am I right?

Comment: @ManikandanS yes, you got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are using `ActiveRecord` method. `ActiveRecord` methods will return boolean values based on the successful/unsuccessful query ran. Using that you can check whether query is successfully ran or not.

For example, save method from `BaseActiveRecord` which is the base class of `ActiveRecord`

```
public function save($runValidation = true, $attributeNames = null)
{
   if ($this->getIsNewRecord()) {
       return $this->insert($runValidation, $attributeNames);
   } else {
       return $this->update($runValidation, $attributeNames) !== false;
   }
}
```